# What is the best approach to balance this equation? Why I cannot do it efficiently?

Tags: equilibrium, stoichiometry

What is the best approach to balance this equation?
$$\ce{CO2 + H2O <--> C2H2 + O2}$$

I did it at first this way and I was not successful: 
\begin{align}
\ce{4CO2 + H2O &<--> C2H2 + 3O2}\\
\ce{2CO2 + 6H2O &<--> 6C2H2 + 5O2}\\
\ce{12CO2 + 6H2O &<--> 6C2H2 + 5O2}\\
\end{align}

Should I start from right side or left? They say start from the most complicated molecule? If it is like that, then what is the most complicated one and why?

Comment: @airhuff Please do not add the reaction tag any more. We are in the process of blacklisting it. See [meta](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3601/4945) for more information.

Comment: Related: http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/68924/what-is-the-simplest-approach-to-balance-a-complex-reaction-equation/70540#70540 (Personally, I'm biased toward my own answer to this question, but I think all of them address how to balance a reaction in general without guesswork).

Answer (score 7):

This may be a bit dumb method, but sometimes I do use it as it is pretty straightforward and doesn't require any guessing. I setup a few equations and try solving over integers.
 $$\ce{aCO2 + bH2O <--> cC2H2 + dO2}$$

Balancing $\ce{C}$ atoms both sides,
$$a = 2c\\$$
Balancing $\ce{H}$ atoms both sides,
$$2b=2c\\$$
Balancing $\ce{O}$ atoms both sides,

$$2a+b=2d$$

Solving gives [this](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=solve%20a%20%3D%202c,%20b%20%3D%20c,%202a%2Bb%20%3D%202d). Not hard to see that $a=4$ does the job.

Answer (score 2):

The key for this type of equation is to balance the diatomic molecule last, and then just add a 1/2 of the diatomic molecule to finish the balance.  Then, double all the coefficients and you're done.

1. balance everything but the diatomic molecule:
   $$\ce{2CO2 + H2O <=> C2H2 + O2}$$
2. Then add the right fraction of the diatomic molecule:
   $$\ce{2CO2 + H2O <=> C2H2 + 2.5O2}$$

Notice that 2.5 oxygen molecules is 5 oxygen atoms.

3. Double all the coefficients to get whole numbers
   $$\ce{4CO2 + 2H2O <=> 2C2H2 + 5O2}$$

Answer (score 1):

There is a standard equation for balancing such reactions:
$$\ce{C_xH_y + [x +(y/4)]O2 -> x CO2 + y/2 H2O}$$

Hopefully, now you should be able to apply it to your reaction. It's just the reverse reaction that you're dealing with.

Comment: Please don't use shorthand or text speak.

Comment: This answer would be more helpful if it demonstrated how the stoichiometric coefficients are found in the first place.